# What's the best gold investment strategy for a Singapore resident?

Tags: investing, india, gold, singapore

I'd like to buy gold in small amounts (1 gm) when the prices are attractive, but I can't keep a watch on it. I'm buying gold as a long term investment / hedge, and I don't have plans to sell it. Liquidity is important, but ability to checkout gold  can be optional. What's the best strategy for me to buy gold?

Are there any services where I can request auto-buy units (say, 0.1 gm steps) whenever the price goes down 1%, or so.

Comment: What country are you managing your investments in?

Comment: @littleadv, Singapore. But, I hope there should be a solution irrespective of my country / citizenship.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I'm not familiar with Singaporean laws, but it is incorrect to assume that there's some "universal" solution. Each country with its own laws, and you need to check locally what your options are.

Comment: The GLD ETF [trades on the Singapore Stock Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDR_Gold_Shares#History), so that's one related option. You could set up periodic investments through your brokerage, although commissions might make this less profitable than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Are we talking physical?

Answer (score 7):

With gold at US$1300 or so, a gram is about $40.

For your purposes, you have the choice between the GLD ETF, which represents a bit less than 1/10oz gold equivalent per share, or the physical metal itself.

Either choice has a cost: the commission on the buy plus, eventually, the sale of the gold. There may be ongoing fees as well (fund fees, storage, etc.)

GLD trades like a stock and you can enter limit orders or any other type of order the broker accepts.

Comment: In small amounts, yes we could buy physical gold easily... but how would we go about selling it?

Comment: Presumably, the seller will offer a price to buy it back. It's important to understand if you buy today at 100, what will the seller offer to buy it back from you or another customer at that moment.

Comment: I suggest ETF rather than physical gold. well it has its own pros and cons though.